# Is the L2 norm always positive?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces, fluid-dynamics

Is

$$\int_{a}^{b} u^2(x,t) \, dx \, , \,\, 0\le t \le T$$ defined as the $L^2$-norm:

$$|| u^2||_{2,[a,b]}^{2} $$

Always positive (or equal to zero)? If not what restrictions do I need to make it so? Or does that just depend on the function $u$

Comment: It is a norm. By definition, a norm is non-negative.

Comment: You have squared $u$ twice where you write the norm.

Comment: Is your function $u$ real-valued? If not, what you have is not a norm.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I mean that's how my textbook defines it. *Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods* by Hesthaven and Warburton.

Comment: That definition with squaring twice is not wrong. otherwise, there would have to be a sqrt around the integral. However, this integral is not the L2 Norm, but the square of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral of a non-negative function is always non-negative, remember that the integral is monotonic: if $f\leq g$, then $\int f\leq\int g$.

Answer (score 4):

The square of a $\mathbb R$-valued function is never negative, and the integral of a non-negative function is never negative.

When $u : X \to \mathbb C$ then the definition of the norm is changed to
$$\|u\|_2^2 = \int \left|u(x)\right|^2 \, dx$$